# How to update records in Microsoft CRM without creating duplicate records while importing through Excel file?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

In CRM 2015 I tried updating the existing data even by creating different duplication rules off but still got an error saying cannot create a record because duplicate record exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `Make this data available for re-importing` when exporting the Excel from CRM.